# javascript - edit buttons within the same div but multiple spans

Tags: javascript, html, yui

I'm looking for a solution to change multiple buttons to an unchecked state each time a button is clicked. Here's the div

```
<div id="season" align="center">
     <span class="yui-button yui-radio-button yui-button-checked yui-radio-button-checked" id="season">
          <span class="first-child">
               <button type="button" id="season-button">Spring</button>
          </span>
     </span>
     <span class="yui-button yui-radio-button" id="season">
          <span class="first-child">
                <button type="button" id="season-button">Summer</button>
          </span>
     </span>
     <span class="yui-button yui-radio-button" id="season">
          <span class="first-child">
               <button type="button" id="season-button">Fall</button>
          </span>
     </span>
     <span class="yui-button yui-radio-button" id="season">
          <span class="first-child">
               <button type="button" id="season-button">Winter</button>
          </span>
     </span>
</div>
```

I can access the buttons by doing:

```
var groupName = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("button")
```

but if I try

```
    for (i = 0; i < groupName.length; i++) {
         groupName[i].set("checked", false);
    }
```

nothing happens

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: `checked` with button? what exactly do you want?

Comment: I'm looking to create a group of buttons that operate like radio buttons, i.e. when one is selected, the previous deselects

Comment: Perhaps use radiobuttons then: that's what they were intended for. If you need the button 'look' you could style the radiobutton's label to resemble a button e.g. `input[type="radio"] + label {/* inactive styles */} input[type="radio"]:checked + label {/* active styles */}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked isn't a valid attribute for `<button>`'s. If you want radio like buttons, use `<input type="radio">` and style them like buttons. Take a look at [the official YUI Grouped Button example](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/button/button-group.html) for how to do this.